# How can I short-circuit a header call that starts a download in PHP?

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I have this code:

```
header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename );
header( 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ), true );
```

It starts the downloading of a file, but before it, I have a :

`do_action(wp_export)`

This is an event in the WordPress space, what I can do is, say:

```
when action wp_export happens, callback these functions.
```

So, how can I say to that script "No, I don't want you to initialize with these headers" before it gets to them?

Comment: how is the script called? Can you give an example of the code?

Comment: @atoms This script is `export.php`, all it does is create a lot of output and then it `echo`es it after I started my download, all of its content then gets put in my file.

Comment: I would pass it a parameter and check for it before executing

Comment: @atoms Forgot to say, there's no way for me to modify this script.

Comment: You cannot output to an html page and provide a file for download at the same time, this is a limitation of HTTP, you need some JS to make it work (and that JS does multiple calls)